# No such project : hxigniter

Tags: php, windows, haxe

I've been trying to install hxigniter library in Haxe using this command in commandline

```
haxelib install hxigniter
```

but i keep getting "No such project : hxigniter"

I followed this link but i got stucked in installing hxigniter : https://github.com/ciscoheat/haxigniter/wiki/Quick-start

Ive already installed Haxe in my Windows 7 PC. I've installed Haxe correctly using the installer. When i type "haxe -version" in commandline, it displays 3.0.1 so i guess everything is ok.

Am i doing something wrong here or is this a Haxe library problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be 3-4 years old, I guess it's Haxe 2 only. You can try to install it from the GitHub using "haxelib git" command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a project this old is probably a red flag unless you want to fork and work on it yourself. For a more current web framework in use with Haxe you may want to consider [Ufront](https://github.com/ufront/ufront)

Also if you are new to Haxelib check out the [haxelib docs here](http://haxe.org/doc/haxelib/using_haxelib) and if you are new to Haxe 3 check out the [migration guide](http://haxe.org/manual/haxe3/migration).